# How to specify location of table on a page

Tags: html, xml

I have two tables.

I want them be near each other and not like now one in one column .

How I can do that ?

And how in general I can specify the location on a page .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>

 <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>


  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This isn't an XSLT question -- you just need to know HTML.

Comment: it's very unclear what you want. what do you mean, 'near each other'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the tables should appear side by side, i.e. the second table on the right of the first one, there are several options:

1. Use the attribute `align=left` in the first table and add the tag `<br clear=left>` after the second time.
2. Do the same in CSS: `float: left` on the first table and `clear: left` on the first element after the second table.
3. Wrap the tables in an outer table, with just one row and two cells, and use `<tr valign=top>` in it.
4. Use CSS positioning.

If you wish to have *some* spacing between tables, the simplest way is to set `margin-left` in CSS for the second table.

Using methods 1 and 2, if there is not enough room for both tables in the visible canvas, the tables will appear as they do now. Using method 3 or 4, horizontal scrolling is forced in that case.

Comment: I will take option number three